# How to decompose table with reference to Heath's Theorem? [Homework]

Tags: mysql, relational-database, decomposition

I have a general understanding of Heath Theorem but I'm having trouble getting my head around this question:

```
Use the functional dependencies to carry out a non-loss decomposition in line with Heath’s Theorem,
to produce a set of tables in 3NF (3 rd Normal Form).

Say why each decomposed table is in 3NF and no longer just 2NF
```

Say I have the following FD:

```
{orderId} -> {employeeId, unitPrice}
```

Does this mean I get the table being decomposed (parent) use SQL to convert it to multiple tables (decomposed). From the above the result would include a table with the fields:

```
orderId, employeeId and unitPrice
```

To explain 3NF vs 2NF do I just confirm there are no longer any **transitive dependencies** in the new table. This is my understanding of the 3NF requirement.

How do I go about explaining all of the above with relation to **Heath's Theorem** ?

Comment: You might have more luck here  http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, I posted the same question there and it has been closed. That site is only for research level computer science.

Comment: Never heard of Heath's theorem... I guess I've been doing SQl for too long. If I understand correctly what it says, I'd guess you'd start with a table (orderId, employeeId, unitPrice), with a FD orderId->employeeId, and realize that your table can be stored as two tables (orderId,employeeId) and (orderId, unitPrice)...